# can not open doc in sharepoint 2013 with office web app

Tags: sharepoint-server, office-web-apps

i have installed office web apps server and sharepoint both 2013 and i have followed every steps in microsoft documents but in the end when i try to create a new word doc in my document library i get these errors

[image]

so i tracked it with uls viewer 
[image]

anybody know whats wrong here ?
i cant figure out what to do please let me know

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the **document library** is shared with the **user** who's trying to create **a new word doc**. That error occurs when the user has no enough permissions.

Comment: i granted every possible permissions to this user , still getting that error

Answer (score 0):

Please logout of SP 
as system admin and login back with user account it should be working.